# Rewrite .htaccess to return 301 and redirect to parent post

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

In Wordpress I have issue that for some reason, when i post new image I get auto-generated URLs that return 404. So post will work file, only we system will also add URL like mysite.com/category/post1/IMAGE/49/myimage.jpg

How can I rewrite that mysite.com/category/post1/IMAGE/49/myimage.jpg
get 301 and go back to mysite.com/category/post1/

Can I say in .thaccess that any URL that have /IMAGE should go back to parent post, so in above case mysite.com/category/post1/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this above your wordpress rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/IMAGE/ /$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```